# Python - invalid syntax in both 2.7 and 3.6, but at different places - revised code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, fedora, psycopg2

My code below is for inserting data into a PostgreSQL database - I've commented out the db code (just trying to print the SQL string instead). However, for some reason, I just can't get past the syntax errors.

I'm using Fedora 28 64 bit.

```
> python2.7 filename.py
```

or

```
> python3.6 filename.py
```

Following insightful comments, I now have a problem with psycopg2 with both 2.7 and 3.6.

2.7

```
[pol@polhost db]$ python2.7 ./ace_2_pg.py 
I am unable to connect to the database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ace_2_pg.py", line 12, in <module>
    cur = conn.cursor()
NameError: name 'conn' is not defined
```

3.6

```
[pol@polhost db]$ python3.6 ./ace_2_pg.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ace_2_pg.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
[pol@polhost db]$
```

I just can't understand it!

Try to install psycopg2, but it's already installed. Has to be, since I've successfully inserted data before now!

python2.7

```
[pol@polhost db]$ pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```

python3.6

```
[pol@polhost db]$ pip3 install psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal
```

I would be grateful if

a) I could be provided with working python for both 2.7 and 3.6, and

b) **much more** importantly, receive an explanation of where it is I'm going wrong!

I've included the input file (very short) at the end for testing - outputting of SQLString is sufficient.

============ python code ======================

```
from __future__ import print_function

import psycopg2

try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='postgres' host='localhost'")
  print ('Connected!')
except:
  print ('I am unable to connect to the database')

cur = conn.cursor()

with open('/home/pol/Downloads/sware/acedb/ace_bis/src/dump/dump_2018-05-18_A_Jade.1.ace') as f:
  for line in f:
    words = line.split()

    print ('Line length is: ' + len(line))

    if "\\" in line: 
      continue

    if line[0:3] == " \\ ":
      print (line + 'beginning of data') 
      continue

    if (len(words) == 3):
      print (words[0], ' 1 ', words[1], '2', words[2], '3')
      SQLString = "INSERT INTO jade VALUES ('" + words[0] + "', '" + words[1] + "', '" + words[2] + "');"
      print (SQLString)

'''
      try:
        cur.execute(SQLString)
        print('Inserted')
      except:
        print('Insert failed')
'''

conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()

    # EOF
```

================= Input file ==================

```
[pol@polhost dump]$ more dump_2018-05-18_A_Jade.1.ace 

 // Class Jade 

Jade "default"
Display  "Chromosome" "jade.maps.Vmap"
Display  "Map" "jade.maps.Vmap"
Display  "Table" "jade.maps.TableDisplay"
Display  "Cell" "lignage.Lignage"
Display  "Node" "lignage.Lignage"

 // End of this dump file 

[pol@polhost dump]$
```

===================================

Comment: There's a missing closing parenthesis at `print ('Line length is: ' + len(line)`.

Comment: Thanks for that - I wasn't even looking there! However now,  both 2.7 **and** 3.6 are failing at code block 1! At least it's consistent :-)

Comment: The shebang is irrelevant and is ignored when you run `python` explicitly.

Comment: I don't get any other syntax errors in this code. Unless that `<-- maybe do this?` thingy is actually part of the code?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - bracket added both in question and locally, thanks for that!

Comment: @chepner - shebang removed both here and locally, thanks for that!

Comment: @chepner now a psycopg2 problem appearing, even though I have it installed! Please see revised question! Maybe a corrupt/messed up install - will reinstall OS!

Comment: @Aran-Fey - now a psycopg2 problem appearing, even though I have it installed! Please see revised question! Maybe a corrupt/messed up install - will reinstall OS!

Comment: If you install the package using `pip`, you probably only install the package for python2. To install for python3, use `pip3`. Try run `pip list` and `pip3 list` to see the packages have been installed.

Comment: Take time to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it benefits you for long run.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - check out error messages! I think there's something wrong with my system - was messing with `virtualenv` and tried to make 3.6 the default and then tried to back that out! Thanks for your input so far! If you can provide something even resembling an answer, I'll upvote it!

Comment: Instead of using `'Line length is: ' + len(line)` and to minimise the mistake of missing `)`. Learn the pythonic way of string concatenation `'Line length is: {}'.format(len(line))`.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain `name conn not defined`:

```
try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='postgres' host='localhost'")
  print ('Connected!')
except:
  print ('I am unable to connect to the database')

cur = conn.cursor()
```

In the `try` block, your code attempts to connect to the database, and fails.
In the `except` block, you code prints `I am unable to connect to the database` *and then carries on.*

In the next line you refer to `conn.cursor()`. But the original assignment to `conn` in the `try` block *failed*, so the assignment didn't take place, so the name is undefined.